# Combining columns of the same name

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a two tables which somehow have the same column name. In the result query, i wish to combine the result which would then occupy the one that are empty.

Here is the structure of my tables:

> position

[image: position]

> accounts

[image: accounts]

> employees

[image: employees]

> students

[image: students]

> ssc

[image: ssc]

> names

[image: names]

> offices

[image: offices]

This is my code:

`SELECT app.approved, p.position, n.fname, n.mname, n.lname, o.office, 
    e.signature, ssc.signature
    FROM approvals app
    LEFT JOIN positions p ON p.position_id = app.position_id
    LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.account_id = app.account_id
    LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.account_id = a.account_id
    LEFT JOIN students s ON s.account_id = a.account_id
    LEFT JOIN ssc ON ssc.students_id = s.students_id AND ssc.removed = 0
    LEFT JOIN names n ON n.name_id = s.name_id OR n.name_id = e.name_id
    LEFT JOIN offices o ON o.office_id = p.office_id
    WHERE app.event_id = '10'`

The actual result is this:

[image: result]

Notice that the some rows of e.signature are empty and the same for ssc.signature, so I wish to combine them, by the way, the SSC can never have its signature in the employees table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the name of those columns that you wish to combine, you need to use the MySQL `COALESCE()` function to return the first non null value found in the list of provided arguments.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Aquaman', NULL, 'Some other dude');
```

This will return `Aquaman`.

In practice, you can use column names instead of raw values. For example:

```sql
SELECT app.approved, COALESCE(e.signature, ssc.signature) AS signature;
```

Note that the `AS signature` part is not necessary but it should that you can choose an alias for the combined field.

Comment: this is it !!! Thank you sir :D It's the first time I have read `COALESCE` though.

Answer (score 0):

If the column name is the same then you can use the alias.

```
SELECT 
p.column1 as p_column1, 
p.product_name as p_product_name , 
s.product_name as s_product_name
FROM products p INNER JOIN suppliers s
```

For more info: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Comment: uhmn no sir, i don't want to do that. Instead, i want to Join them. So there will only one signature in the result query.

Comment: can you explain me your the proper use case?

Comment: It is now answered by @asiby sir :D Thank youu ^_^